# Directory Scanner JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory

Is there a way that i can get all the files and directories on the server using js?
Lets say there is a folder on the server called Files, inside the files folder, there are other folders and files but not a set value and can change constantly. Is there a way to scan the Files folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to list all files in directory on the webserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057931/javascript-to-list-all-files-in-directory-on-the-webserver)

Comment: Not in JS, you need to do this on a server using some server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this wiht a server side script, for example PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

this function returns the dirs, you could nested to get all the dirs and files in directories
then you can return to the javasript with

```
<? echo json_ecnode($array_with_dirs);?>
```

with an ajax Request

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about client-side JavaScript only, no, you cannot do that.  You can read URLs using Ajax.  If a URL corresponds to a file, you've read the file.  If a URL corresponds to a directory and the server responds server-generated index, you could parse that index and recursively read files and indices.  The "crawler" programs used by, *e.g.* Google, employ a similar technique, but do not depend on server-generated indices; they just follow links.

If the files you ask about are not accessible to the web server program, *i.e.* outside the server's document root, then you cannot read them using only client-side code.